# How to show full height view inside showModalBottomSheet in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, modal-dialog

Thank you for reading.
What I'm trying to do is to navigate to a full height view from modalBottomSheet.
The point is I used `onGenerateRoute` when showModalBottonsheet() because there is another navigation that shows same height as modalBottomsheet.

To be clear, there should be 2 navigations from modalBottomsheet.

1. A navigation to a full height view
2. A navigation to a modalButtomsheet that is the same height as parent modalButtomsheet.

As I mentioned I already implemented 2 using onGenerateRoute:

```
showModalBottomSheet(
      context: context,
      builder: (context) => Navigator(
        onGenerateRoute: (context) =>
            CupertinoPageRoute<ProductView>(builder: (context) {
              return const ModalView();
        }),
      ),
    );
```

Since I'm using onGenerateRoute,  I cannot make a full height view anymore using navigator.push().

I would appreciate for any advise. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

as I understood you want to show the full height for " showModalBottomSheet "

to solve this you can use code as below:

```
showModalBottomSheet<void>(
context: context,
isScrollControlled: true,
builder: (BuildContext context) {
  return FractionallySizedBox(
      heightFactor: 1.00, // 1 means full height
      child: Container(
        color: Colors.amber,
      ));
},
```

);

Comment: Thank you I tried it , but it only appears as half height which is same as parent showModalBottomSheet...